# interstitialAd will not show up

Tags: ios8, sprite-kit, iad

i´ve created a SK Game with one viewController and want to view full screen ads but they don´t show up.

in ViewController.m: (viewWillAppear)

```
self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicyManual;
[self requestInterstitialAdPresentation];
```

inAppDelegate.m:

```
[ViewController prepareInterstitialAds];
```

Comment: Where are you actually creating an instance of `ADInterstitialAd `?

Comment: i watched the apple developer video about iAds (2013). they have said there are no further steps neccessary to run iAds

Answer (score 1):

Your approach looks correct, and you are right that you only need those method calls, You may just need to move:

```
[self requestInterstitialAdPresentation];
```

into viewDidAppear, rather than viewWillAppear.

It could be that you are asking for an ad to be shown over a view controller that isn't fully on screen yet and hence it doesn't work.